# Vertically grouping Semantic-ui Labeled buttons

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Recently I started working with `Semantic-ui` and I am stumbling upon a problem which, after trying multiple things, I cannot seem to solve.

I followed the instructions for implementing vertically aligned buttons, found in the `Semantic-ui` docs: https://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html

My case is however a bit different. I want to vertically group buttons which appear alongside a label.

The HTML part of thse buttons are as follow:

```
<div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="ui button">
    <i class="heart icon"></i> Like
  </div>
  <a class="ui basic label">
    2,048
  </a>
</div>
```

resulting in the following:

[image]

When trying to add a vertical grouping container, the horizontal aligned buttons (the labels) seem to be positioned vertical as well:

```
<div class="ui vertical buttons">
    <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
        <div class="ui button">
            <i class="heart icon"></i> Like
        </div>
        <a class="ui basic label">
            2,048
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
        <div class="ui button">
            <i class="heart icon"></i> Like 2
        </div>
        <a class="ui basic label">
            1,121
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result:

[image]

I tried to add a horizontal class to the div's containing the buttons but that doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how I can get the button labels to be positioned as they were initially but keeping the separate button `div's` below each otter (vertically) using `Semantic-ui`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrap only the first in `div` with `vertical` instead wrap both of them.**

```
<div class="vertical">
<div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="ui button">
    <i class="heart icon"></i> Like
  </div>
  <a class="ui basic label">
    2,048
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui labeled button" tabindex="0">
  <div class="ui button">
    <i class="heart icon"></i> Like
  </div>
  <a class="ui basic label">
    2,048
  </a>
</div>
```

**See here:**https://stackblitz.com/edit/semantic-ui-o68elx?file=app/app.component.html

**See output:**

[image]

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: This seems to work for 2 buttons, but when I add a third button it doesn't work.

Comment: so wrap the other one in div with `vertical` class(maybe you can wrap each button in this div)

Comment: your absolutely right. Was kinda obvious but still missed it ;) thanks!

Comment: happy to help:)